# Enunciate Spring annotations API documentation

Tags: spring, maven, documentation, enunciate

I am using Enunciate to generate REST API docs in a maven project.

The artifact `maven-enunciate-plugin` generates Web API docs but it ignores Spring annotations like: `@Secured` (from spring-security)

I tried generating docs with maven artifact that has spring support `maven-enunciate-spring-plugin`, but it does not even generate Web API docs.

Is there a way to configure enunciate or use another enunciate maven plugin so that annotations from Spring are recognized and mentioned in the documentation generated by Enunciate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, I managed to solve this problem by "applying a custom skin to Enunctiate's documentation" (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Applying+a+Custom+Skin+to+Enunciate%27s+Documentation)

I modified `docs.xml.fmt` as well as `docs.fmt` of `enunciate-docs`, so that '@Secured' annotation is recognized.

Unfortunately, for `docs.xml.fmt`, there is no clean way to customize as we have for `docs.fmt`. So, I had to package myself with these modified files.

I referred to how @Deprecated (java.lang.Deprecated) was processed and followed the similar method.

In `docs.fmt` file, add this block just below similar function block of `isDeprecated`

```
[#function isSecured element]
  [#return (getTagValues(element, "secured")?size > 0)/]
[/#function]
```

Now,

Just below this block:

```
[#if isDeprecated(resource)]
 <p class="alert">This resource has been deprecated.</p>
[/#if]
```

add another if block

```
[#if isSecured(resource)]
  <p class="note">This resource is available only to these roles:  
  [#assign securedTags = getTagValues(resource, "secured") /]
  [#if securedTags?size > 0]
    ${securedTags[0]}
  [/#if]

  [#list resource.parent.annotations as tag]
      ${tag}
  [/#list]
  </p>
[/#if]
```

Now, in `docs.xml.fmt` file, just below:

```
[#if resource.parent.annotations["java.lang.Deprecated"]??]
  <tag name="deprecated"/>
[/#if]
```

Add following block

```
[#if resource.parent.annotations["org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured"]??]
  <tag name="secured">

    [#list resource.parent.annotations["org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured"]["value"] as roles]
      <![CDATA[${roles}]]> 
    [/#list]

  </tag>
[/#if]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. Enunciate doesn't recognize those Spring annotations, although that feature could be added. You're welcome to [open up a request](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE) for it.

(The `maven-enunciate-spring-plugin` is just used to have Enunciate wire in Spring to the back-end runtime, it doesn't include the feature you're asking about.)

Comment: I think there already is a similar feature request : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-724

Comment: and somehow also related to this issue:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-618